# Simpson's Paradox (amalgamation)

Tags: statistics

In an attempt to estimate the effectiveness of a new drug, a randomized experiment is conducted. In all, 50% of the patients are assigned to receive the new drug and 50% to receive a placebo. A day before the actual experiment, a nurse hands out lollipops to some patients who show signs of depression, mostly among those who have been assigned to treatment the next day (i.e., the nurse’s round happened to take her through the treatment-bound ward). Strangely, the experimental data revealed a Simpson’s reversal: Although the drug proved beneficial to the population as a whole, drug takers were less likely to recover than nontakers, among both lollipop receivers and lollipop nonreceivers.

Assume lollipop sucking in itself has no effect on recovery. Is taking the drug beneficial?

I understand why the subgroup of drug takers that received lollipops could have a lower rate of recovery than placebo takers who didn't receive lollipops; it's because they are more likely to suffer from depression in the first place, which affects recovery rates.

But how would you explain why the subgroup of drug takers who didn't receive lollipops could have a lower rate of recovery than placebo takers who didn't receive lollipops?

Comment: The problem is not trying to get you to justify reasoning about the drug or behind recovery rates. Think instead about how the patients can be split between lollipop receivers and non-receivers. Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: There seem to me a lot of unanswered questions: 1. What were the sample sizes? 2. Was the sample a simple random sample? That seems implied, but it's not made clear. 3. Were the results statistically significant? 4. Is there any relationship between depression and whatever illness the drug is supposed to treat? 5. It's not clear what the relationship is between the phrase "beneficial to the population as a whole" versus "drug takers were less likely to recover". Presumably the control group didn't get whatever benefit is being talked of?

Comment: @DaveP I've been experimenting with splitting the patients into 4 groups (lollipop receivers and non-receivers, drug receivers and placebo receivers), but don't yet have a resolution to the paradox. Also, doesn't the paradox exist because we don't know the direction of causality of the factors in play? This suggests to me that there is a logical explanation for why the paradox exists.

Comment: I think it is easiest to take it to extremes. Let there be one placebo taker  and many drug takers in the lollipop group. In the non-lollipop group let there be one drug taker and many placebo takers. Then if the one placebo taker in the first group was a success we have 100% success rate in that group. Similarly if the one drug taker in the other group was unsuccessful then there is 0% success rate for drug takers in that group.